# JQuery fadeOut Effect speed/duration not working

Tags: jquery, slider, fadeout

hello every one i am trying to make fadeOut effect on an element in 1 second, but this effect do not respect the speed/duration that i want. the element fade out directly.

here is the link of my code on code pen [enter link description here][1]

```
 [1]: https://codepen.io/ahmadm199/pen/OEEgeB
```

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your source code to your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51001795/edit) it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JS version of what you're trying to do: https://codepen.io/modelcroissant/pen/zaaEbb
I was bored so I decided to build an array based JQuery solution for your problem which also cleans up your functionCeption code and takes away from html to fractionally reduce the html clutter.
BUUUUUT
All you really have to do is remove your css transition styling which is conflicting with your JS code styling.

```css
*{
      -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;

}
```